# Show More/Less Div, Callback functionality

Tags: jquery, callback, hide, show, show-hide

It's a pleasure to meet you all. I'm new at this but a bit too ambitious.

I made a show/Hide Div after skipping some corners, and though it works, it's still sloppy. The delays are intentionally there because I couldn't get callbacks to work. This may be an issue if there is an impossible amount of text in the content box...not to mention, it wouldn't hurt to learn for future projects.

So I am sharing this, asking for critiques since it's very hackneyed, and asking how to get the callback to work in the first place. (and, of course, feel VERY free to use the code if need be.)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YEC5z/5/) is the fiddle.

```
$("#open").click(function () {
    $(this).hide("fast");
    $("#content").delay(50).show("fold");
    $("#close-bottom,#close-top").delay(800).fadeIn(0);
});

$("#close-bottom,#close-top").click(function () {
    $("#close-bottom,#close-top").hide("fast");
    $("#content").hide("fold");
    $("#open").delay(300).fadeIn(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the call back as a second argument after `"fold"` like so:

```
$("#open").click(function () {
    $(this).hide("fast");
    $("#content").show("fold", function() {
        $("#close-bottom,#close-top").fadeIn(0);
    });
});

$("#close-bottom,#close-top").click(function () {
    $("#close-bottom,#close-top").hide("fast");
    $("#content").hide("fold", function() {
        $("#open").fadeIn(0);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YEC5z/6/)

per the [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) documentation the method call with `.show( [duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )` was added in jQuery [1.4.3](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.3/) and supports calling with just `easing` and `complete callback function` (which would maintain the default `400` duration)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!! I keep clicking the buttons to open and close it and getting stupidly pleased that it works, heh. (I could not figure that out for the life of me how to make the syntax work. You're a life saver.)